# "in the trench of morning" meaning

Tags: phrase-meaning

> The orange arc-lamps faded and the crowd depleted a little as they walked along the Stillwater River ***in the trench of morning***.

I googled the phrase, but found nothing useful. Can someone help to explain the meaning of the phrase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an uncommon usage for the word "trench" but a couple of alternative ways to say this that might make more sense could be:

> "...in the depths of the morning."

> "...in the darkest part of the morning."

You often find unusual usages like this in literature.  This would be very unusual in conversation.

Comment: Should we add 'the' in the phrase? "in the trench of the morning" or "in the trench of morning"?

Comment: I believe it works with or without "the".  I prefer using "the" as it seems more natural to me when speaking.  It's your choice though.